# Print every line that doesn't start with null byte

Tags: bash, filtering

I have a text file, and I want to filter out every of it's lines that start with null (`00`) character.

Something like this sample bash script would be sufficient, if `[` only supported binary characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    if [ ${line:0:1} != $(echo -ne '\x00') ]; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The reason why this isn't working is that `read` does not read the null bytes. This is evident from the following: `echo -ne '\x00\x00123\n456\n'|while read line; do echo $line|hd; done`. I don't have a solution in pure bash though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sed

```
sed  -n '/^\x0/!p' filename
```